# How does the "pdf-tools" package overrides "dired-find-file" method?

Tags: emacs, dired, pdftools

After installing **pdf-tools** the **dired** mode opens the pdf file with **PDFView** mode as major mode.

```
(use-package pdf-tools
  :ensure t
  :config
  (pdf-tools-install t))
```

How does the **pdf-tools** package be able to accomplish this?

The **Help** for RET key in dried buffer says it is bound to **dired-find-file**

> RET (translated from ) runs the command dired-find-file (found
> in dired-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function.

I searched for **dired-find-file** in **pdf-tools** installed elisp files and could not find any **advice-add**'s?

Also please explain how can one go about finding arbitrary key bindings like this one?

Comment: I don't have/use `pdftools`. Maybe check your values of `dired-guess-shell-alist-user` and `dired-guess-shell-alist-default`.  (The former should be reserved for you to modify, but perhaps `pdftools` modifies the latter.)

Answer (score 3):

What it modified is not directly related to `dired`, but to how Emacs decides to open files in general. The part of the code that is responsible for that is in `pdf-tools-install-noverify`, itself called by `pdf-tools-install`. The first two lines of the function are:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist pdf-tools-auto-mode-alist-entry)
(add-to-list 'magic-mode-alist pdf-tools-magic-mode-alist-entry)
```

the relevant variables `pdf-tools-<auto/magic>-mode-alist-entry` being constants defined earlier in the file `pdf-tools.el`.

You can check the relevant documentation for `auto-mode-alist` and `magic-mode-alist`, but to sum up, the former is a mapping from "filenames" (or more precisely, file patterns -- typically, regexps matching file extensions) to major modes, and the latter is a mapping from "beginning of a buffer" to a major mode (see also [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) on magic numbers/file signatures).

As to how one can determine that: because it is *not* directly related to key bindings/advices/redefinition of functions, the only "general" option is to explore the "call stack" ! The package tells you to put `(pdf-tools-install)` somewhere in your init file to activate the package, so you can try to see what this function actually does -- and going a bit further, you see that it is essentially a wrapper around `pdf-tools-install-noverify`, which does the real job of setting everything up.